# Which DataFrame representation for readable tests

Tags: python, pandas, restructuredtext

I write a lot of tests (nose based) involving DataFrame.
Those tests should be readable by end-users. DataFrame constructors are not very friendly
to read compared to a plain text table representation.

What about using a text representation like reStructured to construct/assert DataFrame ?

```
=========== =========== ========= ========= ========================
id1         id2         net       nnet      desc
(int64)     (int64)     (float64) (float64) (object)
----------- ----------- --------- --------- ------------------------
1001        1002             10.0       0.0 Closed part of queue
1002                          0.0       3.0 Opened part of queue
=========== =========== ========= ========= ========================
```

The (dtype) line is useful to enforce the columns type to not fail on assert (could be optional).

I need community feedback before coding this reST DataFrame construct/assert feature.
I also think about using ipython notebooks as test cases.

What is your preferred DataFrame representation when readability counts ?

Comment: Forgot to mention that reST representation could also help for documentation (Sphinx)

Answer (score 1):

Constructing from a reST table is not possible, but would be interesting. You can use read_csv to read in a table. See also read_clipboard and read_fwf (fixed width)

```
In [22]: table = """\
   ....: id1         id2         net       nnet       desc
   ....: 1001        1002             10.0       0.0  Closed part of queue
   ....: 1002        NaN               0.0       3.0  Opened part of queue
   ....: """

In [23]: df = pandas.read_csv(StringIO(table), sep='[\s]{2,}')

In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
    id1   id2  net  nnet                  desc
0  1001  1002   10     0  Closed part of queue
1  1002   NaN    0     3  Opened part of queue
```

Comment: Thanks for the regex separator !

The 'NaN' value converted to a np.NaN is also good news.

But I have to find a solution for the dtypes since columns id1/id2 are int64/float64 and make assert fails.

Comment: It is not possible to have NaN inside int64 columns.